# Jquery UI resizeable not working on appended image in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui, dropzone.js

I am trying using Jquery ui's resizeable and draggable on an appended image. It works in Firefox but in Chrome and Safari the appended image doesn't show up at all.

I am using dropzone.js for my file upload. I call one of their functions to get the image:

```
Dropzone.prototype.submitRequest = function(xhr, formData, files) {
      sendFile(formData);
};
```

Then I call my own function to put the image into my directory and append the image to the test div:

```
var sendFile = function(formData){
  console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
        url  : '/MoveFiles.php',
        data : formData,
        type : 'post',
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        success : function(response){
            testing();
        },
        error : function(response){
           console.log('error - ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
};
var testing = function(){

  $(".test").append($('<img src="' + imgPath + '" class="resize-image" />'));
  $( ".test" ).draggable({containment: $("#holder")});
 $('.resize-image').resizable({containment: $("#holder")});

}
```

In chrome and safari when I inspect the element it shows the image was appended to the `.test` div but it doesn't show on the screen. It's not a css issue, I've removed elements to see if the positioning was throwing it off but it still wouldn't show.
When I take off the resizeable function the image shows up and drags just fine. Could anyone see why it would work in Firefox but not Chrome or Safari?

Comment: We still need a bit more code or an example to test with. Please provide more detail to the issue.

Comment: @Twisty I have added more code. Hope that helps, I don't have an example to test with, I am working on the project locally.

Comment: When does `imgPath` get assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I could put together, I made this test:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yd1ppdp4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="holder" class="wrapper">
  <div class="test">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="execute">
  Get Image
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 340px;
  height: 240px;
}

.test {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px 3px 3px 3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.resize-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var testing = function(imgPath) {
    $(".test").append($('<img src="' + imgPath + '" class="resize-image" />'));
    $(".test").draggable({
      containment: $("#holder")
    });
    $('.resize-image').resizable({
      containment: $("#holder")
    });
  }
  $("#execute").click(function() {
    testing("https://il7.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/12588167/thumb/1.jpg");
  });
});
```

This works and allows the Div behind to be dragged, and the image to be resized. I did this in FireFox and moved it over to Chrome & Safari. Both worked fine.

Looking at your new code, it should work as long as `imgPath` is populated with a URL or URI.

Comment: Sorry I missed putting that, imgPath is being populated with the image saved from the MoveFiles file. I see your example works in jsfiddle but not for my code. I'm wondering if it's something with dropzone that's causing it to not work with Chrome and Safari.